# Para abstração de banco de dados, devo utilizar nome de colunas em maiúsculo ou minúsculo?

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, laravel

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação que precisará se conectar com qualquer banco de dados. Estou utilizando Laravel para isto.

O ORM do Laravel mapeia os campos do banco de dados e disponibiliza como atributo a minha classe automaticamente, porém se no banco a coluna estiver em maiúsculo, o Laravel irá criar a propriedade em maiúsculo também:

$Usuario->nome; => $Usuario->NOME;

Para evitar problemas com banco de dados diferentes, qual padrão devo utilizar para nomear não só as colunas, mas também as tabelas do meu banco de dados.

Importante: Não devo depender de configurações no banco de dados, pois essa é uma definição que a aplicação não poderá depender.

Comment: Creio que esses nomes não são *case sensitive*, assim, tanto faz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tudo depende do gosto da equipe e se já existe um padrão ou não na empresa.
Como não existe um padrão 100% vou dar as dicas das regras que sigo, após alguns anos mexendo em banco de dados, e principalmente pelo o fato de você falar que deseja programar para multibancos.

Vamos lá, primeiro um detalhe, Oracle não tem `Lower Case`, é tudo `Upper Case`. Então partindo desta forma utilizo as regras para todos os bancos:

- Tabelas - Tudo em Upper Case
- Uso CamelCase
- Não uso PK composta
- Nome das tabelas tudo em português ou inglês, nada de ficar misturando
- Padrão para PK, FK, CK, UK e afins uso:

  - Nome da tabela_XXyy, aonde o XX é o tipo e yy um número sequêncial. Assim é muito mais fácil encontrar o problema, e também se você pesquisar no banco constraints elas vem na ordem e organizadas
- Sempre uso PK única, mesmo em tabelas N x N. Isto permite simplificar bastante as FK e também a utilização de ORM. Além disto os `joins` são bem mais fácis
- Nas query, sempre utilizo os comandos select, from e afins em lower case, tabelas em Upper Case e campos em CamelCase, ficando bem visual e fácil entendimento as querys

Com estas regras você consegue fazer `select` desta forma:

```
select
  UsuarioID, Nome, Login
from
  USUARIO
order by
  Login
```

Exemplo com join

```
select
  a.UsuarioID, a.Nome, a.Login, a.EmpresaID
from
  USUARIO a
  inner join EMPRESA b on b.EmpresaID = a.EmpresaID
order by
  a.Login
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Obrigado @marlon.tiedt, sua resposta ajudou bastante.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Upper Camel Case` (ou CapitalizedWords) para nome de tabelas e `Lower Camel Case` para nome de campos.

Outras abordagens usando underline podem lhe agradar, mas adote um padrão e divulgue-o. Veja mais sobre [CamelCase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase).

Comment: Meu medo é que pelo fato da minha aplicação mapear esses campos automaticamente (Laravel), se o cliente instalar a aplicação com um banco de dados qualquer, e este especificamente criar o nome das colunas em maiúsculo, nesse caso vai dar problema.

Comment: Se o cliente tiver controle sobre o nome das colunas já era o seu controle!